# Mathematica returns uneditable long solutions for two simple quadratic equations

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to get positive solution(or any solution) of the following two quadratic equations with two variables. My code is:

```
Solve[(1/8)(-A1+x2+α+x1(-2+β)-2 β x2^2-θ x1^2)==0 &&
      (1/16)(A1+3 x2-α-2β x2+x1(-2+3β))^2 - θ x2^2==0, {x1, x2}]
```

It shows that there is large output, then i clicked show fulloutput, it took 5 minutes to display ...and the result is in weird format, there is only one symbol in each line in the last part, and they are very difficult to identify, i can't even find where x2 appears

Comment: It should probably be `β x2` and `θ x2`, not `βx2` and `θx2` (spaces!)

Comment: When I copy your code to my notebook, a lot of syntax errors get highlighted. Please check them first.

Comment: Moreover, slovingn quadratic equations in more than one variable is not as straight-forward as you might expect.

Comment: I inserted `*` between some characters to let it know each half was a separate symbol. And there is a funny character that looks like a thin pale `(` in your first equation that I replaced with an ordinary `(`.  Then `Solve[Eliminate[{youreqn1==0, youreqn2==0},x1],x2]` gives a FAR simpler solution for x2 that you might be able to use. Or you could eliminate x2 and solve for x1. But thus far I haven't found a way yet to get a small simple understandable solution for both. If you put `//InputForm` on the end of that line then you should get a result in a form you can scrape-n-paste elsewhere

Comment: Why do you expect the solution to be simple? Try to solve this cute little system, for example: {x == y^2 + 1, y == x^2 - 2}, and you'll instantly stumble upon a 4th order polynomial equation. Good luck with making its roots look nice.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : LOL - I read your comment of "Morever, *slovingn* quadratic equations..." and scrambled through my recent mathematics rags to see how I could have missed this new class of equations...

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = Solve[(1/8) (-A1 + x2 + \[Alpha] + x1 (-2 + \[Beta]) - 2 \[Beta] x2^2 - \[Theta] x1^2) == 0 &&
            (1/16) (A1 + 3 x2 - \[Alpha] - 2 \[Beta] x2 + x1 (-2 + 3 \[Beta]))^2 - \[Theta] x2^2 == 0, {x1, x2}];

Dimensions[sol]
```

> {4, 2}

So you have 4 sets of solutions each with 2 variables. Is that unexpected?

The standard format of solution is

> {{x1-> ..., x2-> ...}, {x1-> ..., x2-> ...}, ...}

So, you can check them by

```
{x1, x2} /. sol[[1]]
```

for the first set and so on.